# QTextBrowser - Override "Copy Link Location" context menu shortcut

Tags: qt, contextmenu

I have an application that uses a QTextBrowser control to display a website while offline, which is primarily made up of 'relative' links.

Unfortunately, the default context menu for the QTextBrowser "Copy Link Location" action puts the relative link into the clipboard.

I want to intercept that "Copy Link Location" action somehow so I can expand the relative path into the absolute path on the clipboard, so the user can then paste directly into their file manager or "Open file" dialog of another application.

I know how to add additional actions to the context menu, or replace the context menu entirely. However the rest of the default menu is fine so I would prefer not to do that if it is possible.

(Currently using Qt v4.6.2, can upgrade if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

From Qt assistant documentation

> void QTextBrowser::anchorClicked ( const QUrl & link )   [signal]
>
> ```
> This signal is emitted when the user clicks an anchor. The URL referred to by the anchor
> is passed in link.
>
> Note that the browser will automatically handle navigation to the location specified by
> link unless the openLinks property is set to false or you call setSource() in a slot 
> connected. This mechanism is used to override the default navigation features of
> the browser.
> ```

I've found this in Qt4.6.0 help, so it should work in your version

Comment: I am not talking about anchorClicked().
The anchor clicked signal occurs when a link is activated (usually by left-clicking on it, though not necessarily), and is a method of navigating the page.

I want to override one of the actions presented by the context menu that you get whenright-clicking on a link.

Comment: The you may need to override the 
`mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * e )`